# Integrate google drive with Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Is it possible to integrate (store) attachments in Google Drive instead of in Odoo?
So they will be accesible both from Odoo and from external access via Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible you can integrate Google drive into your Odoo project.

You can find it.

- Activate `Developer Mode` -> `General Settings`.
- From there check the box for google integration

[image: Google Drive Integration]

Comment: as far as I understood that integration is for google docs, not for google drive.